# Alpha Value issue in transparency

Tags: opencv

I'm creating an application of watermarking using opencv, I'm not able to set background of image as transparent.
I'm using this code Scalar colorScalar = new Scalar(255,255,255,0); 
Can any body help me how to make background transparent. I'm using PNG format image.

```
targetMat = new Mat(targetSize, scaledImage.type(), colorScalar);
Mat waterSubmat = targetMat.submat((int)offsetY,scaledImage.height(), (int)offsetX,    scaledImage.width());
scaledImage.copyTo(waterSubmat);
center = new org.opencv.core.Point(pivotX, pivotY);
Mat rotImage = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, degreevaluechange, 1); 
Mat resultMat = new Mat(2,3, CvType.CV_32FC1);
colorScalar = new Scalar(255,255,255,0);
Imgproc.warpAffine(targetMat, resultMat,   rotImage, targetSize, Imgproc.INTER_AREA, Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT,   colorScalar);
scaledImage = resultMat.clone();
```

Comment: Do you want the background to be transparent when using imwrite? Can you please provide some more information and code?

Comment: @ØysteinW.    targetMat = new Mat(targetSize, scaledImage.type(), colorScalar);Mat waterSubmat = targetMat.submat((int)offsetY,scaledImage.height(), (int)offsetX, scaledImage.width());scaledImage.copyTo(waterSubmat);center = new org.opencv.core.Point(pivotX, pivotY);Mat rotImage = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, degreevaluechange, 1); Mat resultMat = new Mat(2,3, CvType.CV_32FC1);colorScalar = new Scalar(255,255,255,0);Imgproc.warpAffine(targetMat, resultMat, rotImage, targetSize, Imgproc.INTER_AREA, Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT, colorScalar);scaledImage = resultMat.clone();

Comment: @ØysteinW. Yes i want background transparent

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load your PNG image with the alpha channel and therefore load your image with transparenty, you have to use this code:

```
imread("image.png",-1)
```

You can find more informations in the opencv documentation here:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread

Comment: @Maximum When rotated image is placed on another image than its background area is white, i want transparency in background. I'm using .PNG format image for watermark.

Answer (score 1):

As you see in the documentation provided by Maximus. You need to create a 4 channel Mat:

```
Mat* targetMat = new Mat(targetSize, CV_8UC4, colorScalar);


vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
compression_params.push_back(9);

try {
    imwrite("alpha.png", targetMat, compression_params);
}
catch (runtime_error& ex) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Exception converting image to PNG format: %s\n", ex.what());
    return 1;
}
```

Then add the parameters and write. (This code is from the documentation)

Comment: No success from this too.

Comment: Update your question with more code and please try to help figure things out yourself also. I'd be glad to help you, but there is not enough info. If you can provide some code that I can compile and sort out it be easier..